# Comparing power in FFT frequencies biased by number of bins?

Tags: statistical-power, fourier-transform

I have some EEG data recorded from a mouse with tremor.  When I do an FFT on the data, it generally looks like an exponential distribution.  I'm interested in any frequency peaks that are significantly larger than that expected distribution; that is, a control experiment injecting a tremorgenic drug will produce a peak at 8 Hz, say.

My problem is, I am finding a peak that only shows up when I increase the bin number past a certain point.  Specifically, I'm most interested in frequencies below 30 Hz, and I find a peak at 10.0 Hz, but it only shows up if my bin resolution is 0.5 Hz or finer.  If I set my FFT to give an output at 1 Hz or larger bins, the peak disappears into the background.  That makes me worried that it's some kind of strange electrical noise, since it's tied to such a specific frequency.

Can anyone answer, is increasing the number of bins in an FFT output equivalent to increasing the number of comparisons, leading to more spurious 'significant' peaks?  Or am I ok reporting the 10 Hz tremor as long as it consistently shows up with 0.5 Hz bins and smaller?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are looking into the PSD right? Are you using any windows i.e. welch method?

Comment: Looking only at the univariate distribution would seem to lose some power: aren't "peaks," almost by definition, only *relatively* large spikes within their immediate range of frequencies?  I wonder whether your 10Hz artifact could be aliasing resulting from rounding: how exactly are the original data recorded?